# Ratchet: Should leave it run as a Server via "php" command, manually?

Tags: php, apache, nginx, websocket, ratchet

I'm a LAMP guy, and now start learning WebSockets via `Ratchet`. So far so good following the start up [docs here](http://socketo.me/docs/hello-world), and hence i'm able to run the Ratchet Server, like this:

```
$ php server.php
```

And then my Javascript Clients can connect to it, etc.

### But..

As a LAMP guy, i'm very used to have Apache (or) NGINX as the "Server" for any PHP files to serve to public. Now... should i just run that above command in my terminal, and that's gonna be the Ratchet Server?

Is there a way NOT to run the server like that? (or) Is there a way to let Apache *(as an example)* manage the Ratchet Server? Which means, let Apache start/stop the Ratchet whenever i type:

```
$ service httpd start
$ service httpd stop
```

I'm more confident this way. Plus, the SSL handling, etc also would be then done by Apache more easily. Am i right please?

Please kindly suggest, as i'm very new to this area. Thanks all :)

Answer (score 1):

You indeed are right that running it in the command line is not a production ready solution.

In the last page of the tutorial [(deployment)](http://socketo.me/docs/deploy) there are some ways to do it. For example, hypervisor is entirely explained how to set it up there.

If you don't like hypervisor usage, then you could try to just write a shell script which is executed on startup, that starts the server.php (less good solution, yet easier)

The ssl part you want to use is possible using a proxy with apache.

If you are using Apache web server (2.4 or above), enable these modules in httpd.conf file :

> mod_proxy.so
>
> mod_proxy_wstunnel.so

Add this setting to your httpd.conf file

```
ProxyPass /wss2/ ws://ratchet.mydomain.org:8888/
```

If you have any more questions please let me know.

Comment: Thank you so much for clarifying this. Can Hypervisor simply handle SSL part as well? (But for Apache, mine is 2.2, so it's a headache to compile it again with that Mod.) Else, assume i go with Nginx in the same server. Then can i reside Nginx (for this WS/WSS domain) with the existing Apache (serving for other domains) please? I should then configure Nginx to run only on port 8888. So Apache and Nginx don't conflict each others. Right? :)

Comment: you don't have to recompile apache for this.
If you follow the tutorial from socketo.me you get explained how to set it up.
To add mod_proxy.so you can just do that in the config and no recompilation is needed.

Comment: Erm... i'm following the same doc. Did you mean about the "HAproxy" then, pls?